# return value.utcoffset() is not None AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework-jwt

Pardon me but I am a bit new to Django,

Django does not even tell me the field having issues

I keep getting an error I don't understand

How do I know the field having issues?

When I try to fetch a user profile(Basically a get call) on this model,
see the error I keep getting

I checked a lot of stack overflow posts but none seems to give me the information I need to resolve these errors on this get profile call

```
  File "/MyPath/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/MyPath/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/MyPath/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/MyPath/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/MyPath/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/MyPath/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/MyPath/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/MyPath/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/MyPath/app_features/views.py", line 36, in list
    return Response(serializer.data)
  File "/MyPath/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 745, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "/MyPath/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 246, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/MyPath/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 663, in to_representation
    return [
  File "/MyPath/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 664, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/MyPath/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 515, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/MyPath/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1224, in to_representation
    value = self.enforce_timezone(value)
  File "/MyPath/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1172, in enforce_timezone
    if timezone.is_aware(value):
  File "/MyPath/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/timezone.py", line 212, in is_aware
    return value.utcoffset() is not None
AttributeError: 'datetime.date' object has no attribute 'utcoffset'
```

see my model

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    image_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    is_recurring = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email_verified_at = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    profile_type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    balance = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    tenant_id = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    promo_code = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    formatted_date = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    account_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    father_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    delete_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_logged_in = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    bvn = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=14)
    question_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    question_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    question_3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    answer_1 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    answer_2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    answer_3 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    docType = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    docTypeURL = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures/%Y/%m/%d/', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    countryCode = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    receive_notifications = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_of_birth = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```